Writing a regex regular expression to detect IN conditions with the same column name and replace them
My page receives the conditions as strings in an array from somewhere I can't change. The array values look like this:
$array_conditions[0] = column1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
I have a loop set up to go through these conditions and build the query string, which ends up looking like this:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND column2 IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
So, The issue is, that array can sometimes contain two conditions under the same column name. There are way too many possible columns so I can't treat each individually, and column names can possibly repeat any number of times.
$array_conditions[0] = column1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
$array_conditions[1] = column2 IN (1, 2, 3)
$array_conditions[2] = column1 IN (4, 5, 6)

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND column2 IN (1, 2, 3) AND column1 IN (4, 5, 6)
How would I go about to get an output like one of these two?
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) AND column2 IN (1, 2, 3)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4) OR column1 IN (4, 5, 6)) AND column2 IN (1, 2, 3)
After a bit of searching on PHP functions, I realized regex might be the way to solve this. But I didn't know any regex at all. I tried searching for some solutions online and even studying regex for a while but I haven't come across the solution I've been looking for. All threads I could find could be solved by something like:
(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)(?=,|$)

But a solution like this wouldn't be enough, because I still need to either keep the values inside the parenthesis or keep the whole condition, bring it next to the other condition with the same column name then replace the "AND" with an "OR"
Best thing I managed to get was out from ChatGPT. I can't undestand a thing about it and it can only replace one condition with two matches at a time. I tried coming up with a loop to replace it as many times as needed but I couldn't figure out a way to make it run only if there were still duplicates.
$sql = preg_replace_callback('/(\w+)\s+in\s+\((\d+(,\s*\d+)*)\).*?\1\s+in\s+\((\d+(,\s*\d+)*)/', 
function($matches) {return "({$matches[1]} in ({$matches[2]}) or {$matches[1]} in ({$matches[4]}))";}, $sql);


"My page receives the conditions as strings in an array from somewhere" ...sounds like a valid reason to use a prepared statement and bound parameters.

I forgot to ask if you  were executing this query with mysqli or pdo.

@mickmackusa mysqli. I'm new to SO, should I edit my post with that information?

Using a regex is a good idea, but I would not overcomplicate it.
Here I strip the field names and the values and store it in an array. Then recompose it. With array_unique you can ensure not having duplicates and the intval does some sanitizing.
$conditions = ['column1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4)', 'column2 IN (1, 2, 3)', 'column1 IN (4, 5, 6)'];
$columns    = [];
foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
    $matches = [];
    if (preg_match('/(\w+) IN \((.*?)\)/', $condition, $matches)) {
        $values = array_map(intval(...), explode(',', $matches[2]));
        if (isset($columns[$matches[1]])) {
            $columns[$matches[1]] = array_merge($columns[$matches[1]], $values);
            continue;
        }
        $columns[$matches[1]] = $values;
    }
}

$wheres = [];
foreach ($columns as $field => $values) {
    $wheres[] = sprintf('%s IN (%s)', $field, implode(', ', array_unique($values)));
}

echo implode(' AND ', $wheres);

giving output of:
column1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) AND column2 IN (1, 2, 3)


If the values in your SQL are coming from variables (that are not completely in your control), then a prepared statement should be generated and the values should be passed in as parameters relating to placeholders.
Parse the strings and group the values relating to each unique column name, then populate an array of conditions and an array of parameters.  Then construct the dynamic SQL and pass the parameters to the prepared statement using whatever native function your PHP version allows.  Below execute_query() (available from PHP8.2) is used to conveniently consume the parameters array. (PHPize Demo)
$array_conditions = ['column1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4)', 'column2 IN (1, 2, 3)', 'column1 IN (4, 5, 6)'];

$groups = [];
foreach ($array_conditions as $cond) {
    if (sscanf($cond, '%s IN (%[^)])', $col, $values) === 2) {
        // you might want to check $col against a whitelist here
        $groups[$col] ??= [];
        array_push($groups[$col], ...explode(', ', $values));
    }
}

$conditions = [];
$parameters = [];
foreach ($groups as $column => $values) {
    $values = array_unique($values);
    $count = count($values);
    $conditions[] = "$column IN (" . implode(',', array_fill(0, $count, '?')) . ')';
    array_push($parameters, ...$values);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
if ($conditions) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}

var_export($conditions);
echo "\n$sql\n";
var_export($parameters);
echo "\n---\n";
var_export(
     $mysqli->execute_query($sql, $parameters)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
);

Output (with my own sample db data):
array (
  0 => 'column1 IN (?,?,?,?,?,?)',
  1 => 'column2 IN (?,?,?)',
)
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column1 IN (?,?,?,?,?,?) AND column2 IN (?,?,?)
array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => '2',
  2 => '3',
  3 => '4',
  4 => '5',
  5 => '6',
  6 => '1',
  7 => '2',
  8 => '3',
)
---
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'column1' => 2,
    'column2' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'column1' => 3,
    'column2' => 3,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 4,
    'column1' => 5,
    'column2' => 2,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 6,
    'column1' => 1,
    'column2' => 1,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => 7,
    'column1' => 2,
    'column2' => 2,
  ),
)

Related content implementing various query execution techniques:

Build SELECT query with dynamic number of LIKE conditions as a mysqli prepared statement
Use an array in a mysqli prepared statement: WHERE .. IN(..) query
How to bind mysqli bind_param arguments dynamically in PHP?
Dynamic select mysqli query with dynamic parameters returns error doesn't match number of bind variables
Cannot use positional arguments after argument unpacking while preparing a statement
Is there a shorthand for prepared statements?
Get the row count and all row data from a mysql/mysqli SELECT query


A possible solution would be to break it down to 2 passes.
The first goes through all of the options and extracts the column name and the values (assuming they are all in clauses)...
$groups = [];
foreach ($array_conditions as $condition)    {
    if (preg_match('/(.+) IN \((.+?)\)/', $condition, $matches))   {
        $groups[$matches[1]][] = $matches[2];
    }
}

This would mean you now have a list of the variables and all of the values form the in clauses in one array.
So now iterate over this array and build an array of the conditions, imploding the separated values into one in clause...
$sql = [];
foreach ($groups as $name => $group) {
    $sql[] = "{$name} in (" . implode(', ', $group) . ')';
}

Finally output the array of parts with the and (change to or if needed)
echo implode(' and ', $sql);

which with your sample input gives...
  column1 in (1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6) and column2 in (1, 2, 3)

